# CSS3 Animation Repeat

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to repeat this CSS3 Animation so once it has finished it continues? Any help is much appreciated.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gFCM5/4/)

Answer (score 16):

[Animation iteration count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-iteration-count) is what you are looking for.

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HRP4n/1/

Comment: I always try their example to make sure it works. I know mozilla developer network is better but I go to schools out of habit.

Comment: @james w3Fools.com - now that was a great site. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.